# Exit code of traps in Bash

Tags: bash, signals, exit-code, bash-trap

This is `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function mytrap {
    echo "Trapped!"
}
trap mytrap EXIT

exit 3
```

And when I run it:

```
> ./myscript.sh
echo $?
3
```

Why is the exit code of the script the exit code with the trap the same as without it? Usually, a function returns implicitly the exit code of the last command executed. In this case:

1. echo returns 0
2. I would expect `mytrap` to return 0
3. Since `mytrap` is the last function executed, the script should return 0

Why is this not the case? Where is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Pro-tip: It's a good idea to always use `set -e` and 'set -o pipefail' in your bash scripts. That stops a script as soon as one command fails. It allows you to find errors earlier and abort before doing stupid things on half-baked state.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look the reference from the below `man bash` page,

> exit [n]
>   Cause the shell to exit with a status of n. If n is omitted, the exit status is that of the last command executed. A trap on **EXIT** is executed ***before*** the shell terminates.

You have the debug version of the script to prove that,

```
+ trap mytrap EXIT
+ exit 3
+ mytrap
+ echo 'Trapped!'
Trapped!
```

Consider the same as you mentioned in your comments, the `trap` function returning an error code,

```
function mytrap {
    echo "Trapped!"
    exit 1
}
```

Look the expanded version of the script,

```
+ trap mytrap EXIT
+ exit 3
+ mytrap
+ echo 'Trapped!'
Trapped!
+ exit 1
```

and

```
echo $?
1
```

To capture the exit code on `trap` function,

```
function mytrap {
    echo "$?"
    echo "Trapped!"
}
```

Comment: So there are commands executed after exit? Can I run another exit? What will be the exit code of the script then? Will that cause an infinite trap loop?

Comment: If you put an `exit 1` in your trap code, that would be the exit code of your script.

Comment: @codeforester thanks. And it seems it does not retrigger the trap

Comment: how do I know, in `mytrap` what is the exitcode that the script will be return? (assuming I do not overwrite it by calling `exit` again in the trap function)

Comment: @blueFast in the trap function, check for the value of `$?`, that's always the exit code of the last command, including the one that caused the trap to be called. Moreover, `set -e` and `trap <func> ERR` captures the event that causes the script to abort.

Comment: (Late comment.) If you have `set -e` and your trap handler executes a command which returns a non-zero exit code (subject to the rules suppressing errors) while `set -e` is still in effect, then that exit code will be returned rather than exit code of the last statement of the exit handler, or the original exit code which triggered the handler.