# running sh script on travis CI: The command exited with 1

Tags: bash, sh, travis-ci

I am running an sh script as part of my .travis.yml. It is giving me the error below although the shell script does not fail.

> The command exited with 1.

I tried running the with bash -x to debug and there are no errors.
The problem is that travis thinks that the build failed although it passed.

Comment: What does your .travis.yml look like? what's in the script?

Comment: https://github.com/mosaadm/mooltipass/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/albodelu/mooltipass/compare/c8449c24328b...6432ed767ad4) change [fixes it](https://travis-ci.org/albodelu/mooltipass/builds/240218590).

As explained in the `man bash` page:

> Shell builtin commands return a status of 0 (true) if successful, and
>   non-zero (false) if an error
>          occurs while they execute.  All builtins return an exit status of 2 to indicate incorrect usage.
>
> Bash  itself returns the exit status of the last command executed,
>   unless a syntax error occurs, in which case it exits with a non-zero
>   value.  See also the exit builtin command below.

The last command executed is:

```
[ "$BUILD_CHROMIUM" == 1 ] &&_build_chromium_crx "${zip_file}" "${BUILD_METADATA[${CHROMIUM_TARGET}]}"
```

And it is evaluated as `false` with exit status 1:

```
'[' 0 == 1 ']'
```

So adding `|| true` at the end of this line fixes it. The exit status will always be 0.

Alternatively, use the fix that better suits the expected behavior of your code like `exit 0`, etc.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41619629/1009132) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308207/exit-code-at-the-end-of-a-bash-script):

> exit [n] Cause the shell to exit with a status of n. If n is omitted,
>   the exit status is that of the last command executed. A trap on EXIT
>   is executed before the shell terminates.

So your clean function `trap _clean_chrome EXIT` is not the last to be executed.

Further information about exit status [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html).